# App to stream photos from my Network share to SmartTV via iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos, photo-stream, streaming

I have photos on my network drive. I want to stream them to a SmartTV;  something like:

- On my iPhone
- Open network share
- Find folder with pics
- Stream to DLNA/SmartTV

The *only* app I've found so far is `iMediaShare`. However, it is an old app - and have an issue with the slideshow: you need to manually list all files in the folder,  then start the slideshow (otherwise it will stream only first batch of files).

All other streaming apps do support streaming of my local iPhone Camera Roll, which is fine, but I don't need it.

### Why do I need it?

The software in my TV and media player works slow, and are less responsive. It takes time to navigate to next photo.  It takes time to load stuff. I need to sit in the front of TV and see what is going on. I need to handle different remote controls/apps. Moreover, some of my shares are private, and I don't want TV to access them; but still want to stream some images from it. So, at the end: it is *much more convenient* for me to use it like described above.

Comment: Can't you make your SmartTV access the network drive directly?

Comment: Last time it was not working smooth. Anyway, it is much faster for me to find photo(s) i want to stream on my iphone; and to move to next/previous one. I was also using external media player for the same thing, but again, it works slow. When I use my iphone, it works very smooth.

Answer (score -2):

Try Filpps Tv you can get from apple store

Comment: I dont see anything related Photos on the Filpps TV description? It is the same author, but can you confirm if above is possible?

Comment: Download the free app of Flipps Tv and try out I have it on my phone and can stream my pictures on my TV  You explore the app and yu will find the option therein

Comment: please read the question carefully. I DONT need to stream pictures from my phone, but from my network, via iphone.

Comment: I don't understand why one will like to stream to TV via iPhone and not directly to TV through Network Drive?

Comment: You don't have to understand. Just please help me if you know. See my edit if you really want to.